# Square Contour Show that $|\sin(z)| \ge \sinh(\pi/2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration, hyperbolic-functions

> For $ N \ge 1$, consider the square contour $S_N$ with vertices at $\pi( N+1/2) + i\pi(N+1/2)$; $-\pi( N+1/2) + i\pi(N+1/2)$; $-\pi( N+1/2) - i\pi(N+1/2)$; and $\pi( N+1/2) - i\pi(N+1/2)$. This is a square with side ($2N+1)\pi$ cantered at the origin.
>
> (a) Show that $|\sin(z)| \ge 1$ on the vertical sides and $|\sin(z)| \ge \sinh(\pi/2)$ on the horizontal sides.
>
> (b) Use your solution in (a) to show that $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left|\int_{S_N} \frac{1}{z^{2} \sin(z)}dz\right| = 0$$

I've found a similar solution to proving $|\sin(z)| \ge 1$ on the vertical sides, and I am able to understand the solution, though I am unsure of how to approach the horizontal sides. I've gotten up to $\sqrt{\cosh^{2}(y) - \cos^{2}(x)} \ge \sinh(\pi/2)$ but don't know where to go from here. Also just have no idea how to approach (b).

Answer (score 0):

I just did the first one, it seems long but I just took the parametrization of the lines and then plug them into sin(z), use the identities Felipe gave on class (sinxcosiy+siniycosx etc) and also the definition of sinz (e^iz etc), I don't know but I assumed that N is integer and then it reduces to an easy function, changing billions of variables then find maximum by derivatives which gave out |sinz|>=1..Now onto the 2nd one, it looks ok, just do squeeze theorem from the bounds found in the first one.

Comment: Lol yeah I managed to get part a done. All I did was show $sin^{2}(z) = sin^{2}(x)+sinh^{2}(y) \ge |sin(x)|^{2} and \ge |sinh(y)|^{2}$ which didn't involve derivatives at all... Felipe said N has to be a whole number, so it works out well. Yeah gonna get started on it lol. Btw is it just me or is Felipe making this class unnecessarily difficult

Comment: I don't know, lol. Stopped going to his classes after the first week so I just rely mostly on the book. It's just that he doesn't proofread his hw/exam, like question 2 is wrong definitely. I did derivatives  for proof 1 (|sinz|>=1, and just triangle inequality for the sinhpi/2 one

Comment: Rip he barely covers the basics in class, and honestly I just don't have time to rely on/read the book. Yeah he always ends up needing to correct hw questions lol, and that midterm was brutal. Idk if you know but he's adding I think 15 marks to everyone's mark because of the typos lol. Did you end up figuring out the squeeze theorem thing

Comment: not sure, but I just used the upper bound lemma, so |z^2||sinz|>=|z^2| and then took the limit of that as N approaches infinity.